# How to move UILabel using left or right side?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm new to XCode/iOS and I'm trying to figure out how to move a Label based on the left (or right) side, not the center.

All I can find is something like this:

```
[myLabel setCenter:CGPointMake(x,y)];
```

I've also seen this variant:

```
myLabel.center=CGPointMake(x,y);
```

My question has two parts:

1. How do do something similar, but without using the label center?
2. Is ".center" a property of the `UILabel` object? For example, in MS/VB/C#/etc. objects have ".left, .right, .top, .bottom" for positioning - is there something similar in iOS/Objective-C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`center` is a property of UIView, and no, there’s no equivalent `left`, `right`, or whatever. You need to do the calculation manually: the label’s left side is `label.frame.origin.x` and its right side is `label.frame.origin.x + label.frame.size.width`. If you want to move the label so it’s right-aligned with a particular coordinate, then you can do something like this:

```
label.frame = CGRectMake(100 - label.frame.size.width, label.frame.origin.y, label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: First, thanks! Next: Is there anything that shows some of this SDK info the way you presented it, or is it always a matter of tracing the path(s) through the SDK ? For example, how would I find label.frame ? Thanks Again.

Comment: In XCode: alt-clicking on the UILabel text will open the class documentation for UILabel. That shows the superclasses, methods, properties, as well as links to user documentation and example code. "frame" is actually defined in a superclass of UILabel. But "frame" is a pretty basic property that you will use all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the calculation manually to find X and Y coordinate to use in following code.

```
label.frame = CGRectMake(
label.frame.origin.x, label.frame.origin.y, 
label.frame.size.width, labelSize.height);
```

Comment: Thanks - again, similar to the above responses. I've had to do a lot of this kind of thing in the MS environments when specifics aren't available.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `center` or `frame` to adjust the position of the label.  These are properties of `UIView`.

`frame` returns a `CGRect`.  A `CGRect` is made up of `CGPoint` (origin) and `CGSize` (size).  The origin specifies the left and top coordinates for the view.

```
CGRect frame = label.frame;
label.origin.x = desiredLeft;
label.frame = frame;
```

or

```
CGRect frame = label.frame;
label.origin.x = desiredRight-label.size.width;
label.frame = frame;
```

Comment: Thanks - basically the same as Noah above but useful. I'm used to a more straightforward SDK. Plus I'm used to the MS Visual Studio IDE which has better (I think so far) intellisense for this kind of thing.

Comment: @wayneh yeah, I upvoted Noah, I just gave the added info that a frame is of type CGRect and described the CGRect in more detail.  Same solution, but I was trying to inform you of the fact that the origin is the left and top coordinates.  Hopefully from all the answers and comments here, you can get to the documentation you are looking for.